# Meteor crashed after I did a git init and created a new branch

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm working on a meteor project and it's my first time with Meteor.

Everything was working fine until the moment I decided to do a "git init" into the directory I was working in, followed by a "git checkout -b gh-pages". So that I could post a repo and a live demo here to S.O. because I had a completely different question altogether.

After fiddling around with what used to be easy (creating gh-pages) that process no longer works for me, not sure if GitHub changed their process for creating pages, but for some reason it's not working for me, even after following these instructions: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/

After creating a another branch and attempting to push the code I have to a gh-pages i suddenly started getting these errors.

Sorry this is long:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
W20141230-20:19:22.649(-5)? (STDERR)          
W20141230-20:19:22.735(-5)? (STDERR) /Users/MARS/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.z83ibe++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20141230-20:19:22.735(-5)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20141230-20:19:22.735(-5)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20141230-20:19:22.735(-5)? (STDERR) Error: A method named '/players/insert' is already defined
W20141230-20:19:22.736(-5)? (STDERR)     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1444:1
W20141230-20:19:22.736(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
W20141230-20:19:22.736(-5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object]._.extend.methods (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1442:1)
W20141230-20:19:22.736(-5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].Mongo.Collection._defineMutationMethods (packages/mongo/collection.js:886:1)
W20141230-20:19:22.736(-5)? (STDERR)     at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:208:1)
W20141230-20:19:22.737(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/leaderboard.js:1:50
W20141230-20:19:22.737(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/leaderboard.js:80:3
W20141230-20:19:22.737(-5)? (STDERR)     at /Users/MARS/Desktop/Sandbox/meteor/leaderboard/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:175:10
W20141230-20:19:22.737(-5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20141230-20:19:22.737(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/MARS/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.z83ibe++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
=> Exited with code: 8
```

It did this three times before ending with a "=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change."

Has anyone encountered this before, or can anyone explain why this might be happening?

Here is the only code I have so far:

```
PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');

if(Meteor.isClient){
  Template.leaderboard.helpers({
    'player' : function(){
        return PlayersList.find( {}, {sort: {score: -1, name: 1} });
    },
    'count' : function() {
        return PlayersList.find().count();
    },
    'selectedClass' : function() {
      var playerId = this._id;
      var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
      if(playerId === selectedPlayer) {
        return "selected";
      }
    },
    'showSelectedPlayer' : function() {
      var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
      return PlayersList.findOne(selectedPlayer);
    }
  });

  Template.leaderboard.events({
    'click .player' : function() {
      var playerId = this._id;
      Session.set('selectedPlayer', playerId);
    },
    'click .increment' : function() {
      var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
        PlayersList.update(selectedPlayer, {$inc: {score: 5} });
    },
    'click .decrement' : function() {
      var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
        PlayersList.update(selectedPlayer, {$inc: {score: -5} });
    },
    'click .remove' : function() {
      var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
      alert('Are you sure you want to delete this fool?');
      PlayersList.remove(selectedPlayer);
    }
  });

  Template.addPlayerForm.events({
    'submit form' : function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var playerNameVar = event.target.playerName.value;
      var playerScoreVar = event.target.playerScore.value;

      PlayersList.insert({
        name: playerNameVar,
        score: playerScoreVar
      });

      var formAddPlayer = document.getElementById('formAddPlayer');

      formAddPlayer.reset();
    }
  });
}

if(Meteor.isServer){

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: My vote for the most apocalyptic question title in stack overflow :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `A method named '/xxx/insert' is already defined` is a bit obscure, but it means you have this bit of code running on your server twice.

```
PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');
```

Given that you have it once at the top of your file you should look for it elsewhere in your directory.

I'm not sure what git did specifically but the error is a result of a collection being defined twice so somewhere in the directory there must be a duplicate chunk of code.

Comment: yes i appears that when i cloned the repo that i created on github and created it as an orphan that it duplicated the code and created a directory inside of my root directory, so somewhere in there was a conflict. I just removed that interior directory that i just mentioned and I was good to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue like this before. What fixed it for me was just running `git clean -dfx`
I don't really see anything wrong with your code that should throw that error. It may just be git being strange.

Comment: Great tip on the git clean -dfx, never used that before.